# git bisect in one command

Tags: git, git-bisect

I think `git bisect` requires too much typing.

To check the last N commits I have to do:

```
user@host> git bisect start HEAD HEAD~10
user@host> git bisect run py.test -k test_something
 ...
c8bed9b56861ea626833637e11a216555d7e7414 is the first bad commit
commit c8bed9b56861ea626833637e11a216555d7e7414
Author: ...
Date:   Thu Apr 16 16:52:41 2015 +0200

    - Commitmessage: ....

user@host> git bisect reset
```

It would be nice to have this in one command

Example:

```
git bisect --start HEAD~10 run py.test -k test_something
```

With one command I don't mean a shell line separated by semicolons :-)

Comment: Is this a feature request or a question?

Comment: @Misch for me (no git expert) it is a question.

Comment: Having a quick look at the documentation, I'd say it isn't possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation is not possibile, but maybe you can find useful this project [grosser/git-autobisect](https://github.com/grosser/git-autobisect) if you have a test to run.